# "Unable to start program...system cannot find the file specified" error in Visual Studio when writing C

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am new to C, so I was writing really basic code on Visual Studio. The first program (Hello World) worked out perfectly, but when I added a second program (a loop), I get

> unable to start program, System could cannot find the file specified

Exact error (I added the 3 dots in the file path for privacy reasons)

```
-----
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Unable to start program 'C:\Users ... Learning Projects\Learning\Debug\Learning.exe'.

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

First program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//links the program with the standard input output file
//contains functions like printf 

//main function  
int main() {

    printf("hello World \n");
    return (0);
}
```

Second program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int ch; 
    for (ch = 75; ch <= 100; ch++) {
        printf("ASCII value = %d, Character = %c\n", ch, ch); 
    }

    return (0); 
}
```

This may be a stupid problem, but I am unable to figure out what is causing it.

Comment: Pay attention to the output window when you compile. It will tell you if the build succeeds or fails, and if it fails it will tell you why.

Comment: Thanks! I looked and apparently I can't have multiple main() functions in a single project or something?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `#include` incorrectly. The compiler is telling you that it could not find the file you wished to include.

When you say

```
#include "stdio.h""
```

You should say instead

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: But `#include "stdio.h"`  with a single ending double-quote should also work

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch perhaps, but that would be introducing an unnecessary difference in the two programs. Especially when learning, one should change one thing at a time.

Comment: My bad, I changed it originally to  see if that would fix the error. The same error still occurs